# Parameters in SQL should be ignored if I don't mention the value

Tags: sql, oracle

Well If I am writing a SQL statement like this:

```
select employee, deptno, data, lead 
from emp 
where emp.deptid = dept.deptid
```

and

```
deptno =:p_department_no
```

The above is an example so please do ignore any mistakes well if I pass the department no: 10 it will display dept 10 list if I leave the parameter column empty it shows empty record. I want to see all record if I don't pass any parameter.

Comment: Add in the WHERE clause:  `where deptno = :p_department_no OR :p_department_no is NULL`. Also: what the heck is the condition `dept no = deptno`? (Obviously an identifier can't have spaces in it, let's begin with that.)

Comment: I like how the user implied they posted pseudocode and the first two comments are syntax corrections. :D

Comment: @mathguy is there any way we can use the case statement. as above was a mistake corrected.

Comment: Yes, you can do it with a CASE statement - not sure of the benefit though, unless you know which version of the query will be used more often (with given value to the parameter, or with NULL to get all the rows).

Comment: Also: Your correction makes no sense. If you are selecting from TWO tables (join) then show both tables in the FROM clause. I will not help fix trivial mistakes in a very simple query - that's not what SO is for.

Comment: There is an optimisation for `where deptno = nvl(somevar,deptno)` but it will exclude rows where `deptno` is null (that is, passing a null `somevar` will return all rows with non-null `deptno`), so this question is easier for mandatory columns.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson that works great for me right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you pass a `null` value for parameter `p_department_no` (*when you do not have a value*) you could use [COALESCE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions023.htm#SQLRF00617) which would make the 2nd comparison statement in the `WHERE` always evaluate to true. This will work only if the `deptno` column is not nullable as if there are null values the expression will then evaluate to false for those records.

```
SELECT employee, deptno, data, lead 
FROM emp 
WHERE emp.deptid = dept.deptid
AND deptno = COALESCE(:p_department_no, deptno)
```

---

From comment below which is relevant if you have an index on the column `deptno`:

> [@WilliamRobertson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/230471/william-robertson) - If you use [NVL](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions110.htm#SQLRF00684) in place of COALESCE you can take advantage of an optimisation whereby the execution will use the index at runtime if :p_department_no is not null.

The resulting sql statement would then be:

```
SELECT employee, deptno, data, lead 
FROM emp 
WHERE emp.deptid = dept.deptid
AND deptno = NVL(:p_department_no, deptno)
```

Comment: it worked the same exact to William so what would be the best one to use coalesce or NVl

Comment: If you use `NVL` in place of `COALESCE` you can take advantage of an optimisation whereby the execution plan will conditionally use the index at runtime if `:p_department_no` is not null. This has been around since Oracle 9i days so perhaps it predates `COALESCE`. It has to be `NVL` specifically. (Of course if there's no index on that column then it makes no difference which you use.)

Comment: @WilliamRobertson - thank you for that, I was not aware. I updated the answer to include this.